# When called with an action of type "SET_MAX_VALUE", the slice reducer for key "products" returned undefined

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, undefined, action

Excuse me, I hope if you could help with something. I am working on a e-commerce website project with React and Redux. I have a price filter component which consists of two input fields. The first input field takes the minimum price value and the second field the maximum field.

This is my Price Range Component:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/index';
import '../../styles/components/priceRanges.css';

const PriceRanges = (props) => {
    const minInputValue = useSelector((state) => state.products.minValue);
    const maxInputValue = useSelector((state) => state.products.maxValue);
    const minDefaultValue = useSelector((state) =>
        Math.min(...state.products.products.map((p) => p.price)),
    );
    const maxDefaultValue = useSelector((state) =>
        Math.max(...state.products.products.map((p) => p.price)),
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const minInputRef = useRef();
    const maxInputRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            if (
                minInputValue === minInputRef.current.value &&
                maxInputValue === maxInputRef.current.value
            ) {
                return dispatch(actions.filterByPrices(minInputValue, maxInputValue));
            }
        }, 800);
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [dispatch, maxInputValue, minInputValue]);

    return (
        <div className="price-range-container">
            <div className="price-range-input-row row">
                <div className="price-range-input">
                    <input
                        ref={minInputRef}
                        id="min-input"
                        name="min-input"
                        type="text"
                        className="price-min-range"
                        placeholder={minDefaultValue}
                        onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.setMinInputValue(e.target.value))}
                        value={minInputValue}
                    />
                </div>
                to
                <div className="price-range-input">
                    <input
                        ref={maxInputRef}
                        type="text"
                        className="price-max-range"
                        placeholder={maxDefaultValue}
                        onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.setMaxInputValue(e.target.value))}
                        value={maxInputValue}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PriceRanges;
```

This is also my code for the SET_MAX_VALUE action and helper function for setting max value and filtering products by prices,

```js
export const setMaxInputValue = (maxValue) => ({
    type: actionTypes.SET_MAX_VALUE,
    maxValue,
});
export const filterByPrices = (minPrice, maxPrice) => ({
    type: actionTypes.FILTER_BY_PRICES,
    minPrice: Number(minPrice),
    maxPrice: Number(maxPrice),
});

const initialState = {
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: [],
    productId: '',
    product: '',
    minValue: '',
    maxValue: '',
    minPrice: '',
    maxPrice: '',
    checkedCategories: [],
    categories: [],
    loadingProducts: false,
    errorFetchingProducts: false,
    errorFetchingCategories: false,
};

const filterByPrices = (state, action) => {
    let updatedFilteredProducts;
    let minPrice = 0;
    let maxPrice = 0;

    if (action.minPrice === 0 || action.maxPrice === 0) {
        return updateObjects(state, {
            filteredProducts: [...state.products],
            minPrice: minPrice,
            maxPrice: maxPrice,
        });
    } else {
        minPrice += action.minPrice;
        maxPrice += action.maxPrice;
        if (maxPrice >= minPrice) {
            updatedFilteredProducts = [
                ...state.products.filter(
                    (p) => p.price >= minPrice && p.price <= maxPrice,
                ),
            ];
            return updateObjects(state, {
                filteredProducts:
                    updatedFilteredProducts.length > 0 && updatedFilteredProducts,
                minPrice: minPrice,
                maxPrice: maxPrice,
            });
        }

        return updateObjects(state, {
            filteredProducts: [...state.filteredProducts],
            minPrice: minPrice,
            maxPrice: maxPrice,
        });
    }
};
```

Everything works fine, until I am trying to erase the inserted value in one of the input text fields. Once the input value is cleared from the text field, an error occurs:

> Error: When called with an action of type "SET_MAX_VALUE", the slice reducer for key "products" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

I think I understand why it happens, but I would like if anybody could explain to me why is this happening and what could I do avoid this bug or error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Return null instead of undefined.

```
export const setMaxInputValue = (maxValue) => ({
    type: actionTypes.SET_MAX_VALUE,
    maxValue: maxValue || null,
});
```